# AppCode iOS application: Group folders not visible?

Tags: ios, appcode

P.S. I am new to both `AppCode` and `iOS`

I added 2 groups `menu` and `summary` and added somefiles to it. I accidentally reverted some file hides these folders from project structure

[image]

But as you can see, these are available on filesystem

[image]

How do I get them back on project structure? I can't even search for them in AppCode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AppCode right click on the pennyapp-ios group, click Add->Files...  Choose your two folders and select "create groups for added folders."